# Android inflating views

Tags: android

Difficult to try and phrase this question, but I will try my best.

Basically, I have an application and I would like to split the code up more. To try and explain this, will give an example of one of my screens.

In my home screen, I have a title, user details, balance, next bill details and usage details. I want to split each of these sections into their own views. So what I have in my main XML file is I have 5 different RelativeLayouts, like this

```
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/layout1">


</RelativeLayout>
```

One for each function I want to have on my home screen. And as you can see I also have each layout set below the previous layout, so the order is title, layout1, layout2, layout3, layout4. (The reason I am doing this is, that I want each layout to be interchangable, i.e. I could remove layout2, and order then be title, layout1,layout3,layout4 as I may not need the 2nd layout depending on what is required of the app)

So in my main activity class, I have called each of these layouts.

```
    layoutTitle = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.title);
    layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    layout3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    layout4 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout4);
```

Then I use layout inflator like so

```
View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userdata, null);
```

to set up the layout for each layout I have defined in my xml file.

What I want to know is, is it possible to inflate another activity rather than an XML file? The reason I ask this is, that each function I said the home screen is made up of, title, user details, balance etc, I have an activity for each of these. Each of these functions has custom functionality that I have designed, such as animation etc. If I simply inflate these xml files, then I can't access the widgets inside so I can't set up the functionality from Java which is what I need.

If I was able to inflate another activity, then this would not be a problem, as I would set up the functionality for each function in activity, then just inflate that class.

I hope my question was clear, if not I can expand on any areas you are not sure about.

Would be very grateful for any assistance!!

EDIT: If it is not possible to inflate a class, then is there any other way method you could recommend that could solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do exactly the same as you.

I use **composition** in my Java activities to achieve the sharing of functionalities across my activities. I think of activities as "context", and not as parts of my page that get replicated. So when I am in a certain context (an activity), I then display layout1, layout2 and layout3 with specific parameters, and specific contents that depends on that activity. On another activity, layout1, 2 or 3 could be different, but they have the same location on my screen all the time.

I use composition through views: all my activities have a superclass (call it anything you want, something like `ActivityWithCustomLayout`, which contains all my layout as class members (as `ViewGroup`). They are protected, so each of the variables `layout1`, `layout2` and `layout3` are available to all subclass activities of this superclass.

And when on a specific activity, I populate each of the layouts on my `onCreate` method with:

```
layout1.addView(...something inflated from an XML that depends on that specific activity...);
layout2.addView(...same principle...);
```

So in fact all my XML layouts are "parts" of activities, which I inflate at runtime into views, that I add dynamically to my activity when needed.

You're right, these explanations are not easy :)

---

If you target Android >= Honeycomb (including ICS) then have a look at the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) framework, it may be a simpler way to achieve all of that (haven't had a look at that yet).

Comment: +1 for the Fragments suggestion.  You can use Fragments on 1.6 or higher by including the compatibility library: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Yes I know, I really need to look into that Fragment framework, that would probably make my applications easier to manage and refactor. Oh well.

Comment: +1 for Fragments aswell. Seems to be ideal for exactly this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, think I am going to try doing same technique as Guillaume for today and then will try out fragments tomorrow. Have not heard of or used the fragments feature before,  so looking forward to trying it out

Comment: Just finished implementing it same way as you do Guillaume, and it works absolutely perfectly, I can't believe I didn't think to use a superclass in the first place :P Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not too much of an answer but I often find myself subclassing the layouts themselves. Then, in the `onFinishInlate()` callback, I wire up all of my view references using `findByViewId`. In your XML, you can replace `<RelativeLayout>` with `<com.company.CustomLayout>`, assuming that your `CustomLayout` is a subclass of `RelativeLayout`.

As mentioned, you can then pull them out into separate files and include them with the `include` tag. This makes refactoring easy and allows you to reuse the layout components.

Or, if you inflate these subclassed layouts from within your code, you don't have to worry about all the messy `findViewById` calls in your activity.

Fragments are also great and have similar life cycles to an activity. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need to inflate all of those Views from within your Activity.  Look into using the `include` and `merge` tags within your Layout.  This should help get you started: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

You can also toggle the visibility of your Layouts.  So, you can declare them in XML, initialize them as `visibility="false"`, and then toggle that visibility in your Java code.

You also stated: *"If I simply inflate these xml files, then I can't access the widgets inside so I can't set up the functionality from Java which is what I need."*

You can access any Layout component after it has been added to your Activity using `findViewById` and casting the object it returns to the appropriate type.