# Issue in Custom Spinner

Tags: android

Clicking on the drop down arrow of the First image, the drop down list in the Second image is going to visible. I won't be able to understand how to do that. Please help me to solve this issue.

#### First image

[image: First image]

#### Second image

[image]

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. [Have you tried inflating your layout?](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android inflating views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475554/android-inflating-views)

Comment: it definitely is not a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

The widget you are talking about is not `Spinner` but you can easily implement that kind of looks using
 `ExpandableListView` , you just need to customize it

you can find complete example here [custom ExpandableListView example](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)